# memory leak for assigned strings in heap?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

My code uses a heap memory allocator. The leafNode object referenced in the code below is the result of casting a heap ptr obtained from the allocator to the struct: leafNode. the leafNode struct contains an array of std::string and another array of RID objects, no other fields. Since I am manipulating these strings(in keyArray) on the heap, I think they're not getting cleaned up properly on assignment. Running valgrind, I see output like the following. How should I avoid these memory leaks?

```
11 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 20
==5952==    at 0x4837DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==5952==    by 0x49D1A1F: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.tcc:265)
==5952==    by 0x49D1D9D: assign (basic_string.h:1366)
==5952==    by 0x49D1D9D: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:695)
==5952==    by 0x11DC11: void db::Index::insertIntoLeaf<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, db::LeafNodeString, db::NonLeafNodeString>(db::RIDKeyPair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, db::LeafNodeString*)
```

leafNode struct:

```
struct LeafNode {
  std::string keyArray[STRINGARRAYLEAFSIZE2];
  RecordId ridArray[STRINGARRAYLEAFSIZE2];
};
```

Here is the code for the insertIntoLeaf function:

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < leafOccupancy; i++) {
  if (leafNode->ridArray[i].page_number == 0 ||
      entry.key <
          /*=*/leafNode->keyArray[i]) {  // no duplicates so no need for <=
    index = i;

    if (leafNode->ridArray[index].page_number != 0 &&
        index < leafOccupancy - 1) {
      std::rotate(&(leafNode->keyArray[index]),
                  &(leafNode->keyArray[leafOccupancy - 1]),
                  &(leafNode->keyArray[leafOccupancy]));
      std::rotate(&(leafNode->ridArray[index]),
                  &(leafNode->ridArray[leafOccupancy - 1]),
                  &(leafNode->ridArray[leafOccupancy]));
    }
    leafNode->keyArray[index] = entry.key;

    leafNode->ridArray[index] = entry.rid;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing any string assignments. Are you compiling with inlinig disabled?

Comment: any assigment to keyArray[index] is a string assignment

Comment: Can you pare it down to a [mcve] with the same complaint from valgrind?